# Samsung Smart TV SDK Documentation

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I've recently started developing some small apps on the Samsung Smart TV SDK.

I've been searching for some guide/introductory documentation on the SDK, to no avail. 
http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/ has a lot of specific examples, but no general information on the architecture of the SDK.

This (http://www.scribd.com/doc/51800086/2010-App-Development-Guide-for-Internet-TV-V1-09) is the only thing I've found, but its outdated.

It uses the /CSS /JavaScript /Resource config.xml index.xml hierarchy, while it seems the "new" hierarchy of projects has changed (scenes etc)

Am I not searching hard enough or is the documentation a bit scarce?

Answer (score 1):

See here for the SDK archives and release note for that.

http://www.samsungdforum.com/Devtools/SdkArchive

[Look here for the guide](http://www.samsungdforum.com/upload_files/files/guide/data/html/html_3/cover_page.html)